# Why won't this script accept any arguments?

Tags: scripting, solaris, shell

I'm trying to write an SVN post-commit hook and, strangely, am getting hung up on what should be the easiest part.

**The Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
set REPO="$1"
set REV="$2"

set SVNBIN="/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/"
set SSHBIN="/usr/bin/ssh"

set HOST="staging.domain.net"
set timeout=30
set USERNAME="svn-usr"

set E_NO_CONNECT=2
set E_WRONG_PASS=3
set E_UNKOWN=25

set CHANGED=`"$SVNBIN"svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`
echo "Here are changes: $CHANGED" >> /var/svn/repos/www/logs/testing
echo "Command: $0; Repo: $REPO; Rev: $REV; Total: $#" >> /var/svn/repos/www/logs/testing
set PROJECT ""
```

Yet when I call it, it doesn't seem to be seeing the arguments I pass to it:

```
/var/svn/repos/www/logs> sudo ../hooks/post-commit /var/svn/repos/www 33
svnlook: missing argument: --revision
Type 'svnlook help' for usage.
/var/svn/repos/www/logs> cat testing
Here are changes:
Command: ../hooks/post-commit; Repo: ; Rev: ; Total: 1
```

This is on a Solaris 10 SPARC box.

I'm a bit of a script newbie, but shouldn't this be really easy??

Comment: csh uses the `set` keyword in that way. sh doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set` doesn't do what you think it does: it modifies the positional arguments `$1`, `$2`, ... `$@`, etc. It doesn't assign variables.

```
set REPO="$1"
set REV="$2"
```

should be:

```
REPO="$1"
REV="$2"
```

(etc)

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  Why does $# still only return 1 though?

Comment: cuz you're accessing $# after modifying the positional parameters using 'set'.

Comment: @Nate Wagar: Because $# is also defined in terms of the positional parameters. Read the BASH manual page, and read especially the parts about Positional Parameters and Special Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have all those `set` commands, remove them and see if works?

Comment: Because "I'm a bit of a script newbie" :P

Answer (score 0):

```
REPO="$1"
REV="$2"

SVNBIN="/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/"
SSHBIN="/usr/bin/ssh"

HOST="staging.domain.net"
timeout=30
USERNAME="svn-usr"

E_NO_CONNECT=2
E_WRONG_PASS=3
E_UNKOWN=25

CHANGED=`"$SVNBIN"svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`
.....
PROJECT=""
```